How to assign dictionary to passthrough in Langchain
I trying to use make custom chain by function with RunnableLambda. I faced problem when "I trying to assign function that returns dictionary" with RunnablePassThrough or RunnableAssign.
here are example code using RunnablePassThrough:
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.runnables import chain, RunnableAssign, RunnablePassthrough, RunnableLambda
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

@chain
def generate_and_parse_response(inputs):
    llm_chain = (
        PromptTemplate.from_template("""Follow this output format:
            <OUTPUT>
            [Rationale]: (Reasoning behind generating the response)
            [Response]: (Your generated response)

            here is input query
            [Query]
            {query}
                                     
            Now, generate
            [OUTPUT]""")
        | ChatOpenAI()
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    raw_response = llm_chain.invoke(inputs)
    rationale = raw_response.split("[Rationale]:")[-1].split("[Response]:")[0].strip()
    response = raw_response.split("[Response]:")[-1].strip()
    return {"raw_response": raw_response , "rationale": rationale, "response": response}

response_chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(
        raw_response=generate_and_parse_response|itemgetter("raw_response"),
        rationale=generate_and_parse_response|itemgetter("rationale"),
        response=generate_and_parse_response|itemgetter("response")
    ) # <-- generate_and_parse_response called tree times.
)

print(response_chain.invoke({"query": "What is the capital of Korea?"}))

# expected output
# {'query': 'What is the capital of Korea?', 
# 'raw_response': '[Rationale]: blah1 blah1 [Response]: blah2 blah2',
# 'rationale': 'blah1 blah1', 'response': 'blah2 blah2'}

Possible solution is separating the chain. but not my point.
for example:
@chain
def generate_response(inputs):
    llm_chain = (
        PromptTemplate.from_template("""Follow this output format:
            <OUTPUT>
            [Rationale]:(Reasoning behind generating the response)
            [Response]:(Your generated response)

            here is input query
            [Query]
            {query}
                                     
            Now, generate
            [OUTPUT]""")
        | ChatOpenAI()
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    return llm_chain.invoke(inputs)

response_chain2 = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(raw_response=generate_response)
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(
        rationale=itemgetter("raw_response")|RunnableLambda(lambda x: x.split("[Rationale]:")[-1].split("[Response]:")[0].strip()),
        response=itemgetter("raw_response")|RunnableLambda(lambda x: x.split("[Response]:")[-1].strip())
    )
)

print(response_chain2.invoke({"query": "What is the capital of Korea?"}))

I tried to use RunnableAssign but didn't works with RunnableLambda.
here is expected code format:
# expected format but didn't work.
response_chain = (
    RunnableAssign(generate_and_parse_response)
)
    
print(response_chain.invoke({"query": "What is the capital of Korea?"}))

returns following errors
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for RunnableAssign mapper
value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

Is there elegant way to do this?

The main point of this question seems to be whether it is possible to know the key values of the dictionary resulting from executing RunnableLambda. The related question can be found at HERE. The subsequent issue appears to be how to implement this.
